# The following argument(s) are not supported with the native Keras format: ['options']

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a Keras deep learning Algorithm on dogs vs cats dataset. I am able to run my code in colab. But in Jupyter lab I am getting this error.

```
The following argument(s) are not supported with the native Keras format: ['options']
```

Below is the code:

```
import os
import shutil
import pathlib

original_dir = pathlib.Path("/content/drive/MyDrive/Reva/dogs_vs_cats/train/train")
new_base_dir = pathlib.Path("/content/drive/MyDrive/Reva/dogs_vs_cats/")

def make_subset(subset_name, start_index, end_index):
    for category in ("cat", "dog"):
        dir = new_base_dir / subset_name / category

        # Check if the folder exists and delete it if it does
        if os.path.exists(dir):
            shutil.rmtree(dir)

        # Create the folder again
        os.makedirs(dir)

        fnames = [f"{category}.{i}.jpg" for i in range(start_index, end_index)]
        for fname in fnames:
            shutil.copyfile(src=original_dir / fname,
                            dst=dir / fname)

make_subset("train", start_index=0, end_index=1000)
make_subset("validation", start_index=1000, end_index=1500)
make_subset("test", start_index=1500, end_index=2500)

from tensorflow.keras.utils import image_dataset_from_directory

train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    new_base_dir / "train",
    image_size=(180, 180),
    batch_size=32)
validation_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    new_base_dir / "validation",
    image_size=(180, 180),
    batch_size=32)
test_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    new_base_dir / "test",
    image_size=(180, 180),
    batch_size=32)

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(180, 180, 3))
x = layers.Rescaling(1./255)(inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="rmsprop",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath="convnet_from_scratch.keras",
        save_best_only=True,
        monitor="val_loss")
]

history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=30,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    callbacks=callbacks)
```

I need to know how to resolve the above code. Any suggestions to improve the time required to run the code is also welcome.

Comment: It runs for me with the following dummy data:  
`train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((tf.random.normal((100, 180, 180, 3)), tf.random.normal((100, 1))))`
`validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((tf.random.normal((100, 180, 180, 3)), tf.random.normal((100, 1))))`
Can you post your dataset creation?

Comment: I am using Cats vs Dogs data set and trying to run that code here:

Comment: def make_subset(subset_name, start_index, end_index):
    for category in ("cat", "dog"):
        dir = new_base_dir / subset_name / category

        os.makedirs(dir)

        fnames = [f"{category}.{i}.jpg" for i in range(start_index, end_index)]
        for fname in fnames:
            shutil.copyfile(src=original_dir / fname,
                            dst=dir / fname)

make_subset("train", start_index=0, end_index=1000)
make_subset("validation", start_index=1000, end_index=1500)
make_subset("test", start_index=1500, end_index=2500)

Comment: import os
import shutil
import pathlib

original_dir = pathlib.Path("/content/drive/MyDrive/Reva/dogs_vs_cats/train/train")
new_base_dir = pathlib.Path("/content/drive/MyDrive/Reva/dogs_vs_cats/")

Comment: Can you please edit the code into your question as a code block? It's not really readable this way.

Comment: Can you test the following code for me? `python3 -c "import keras;print(keras.saving.saving_lib.saving_v3_enabled())"`. I dug into the TF/Keras library and indeed, when trying to save in the native `keras` format, it throws an error when giving options, which tf natively does. For me, the python code prints `False`, so it does not save in the natural keras format.

Comment: I tried to replicate it with different Keras versions, the one on colab for me was 2.12 (the same as my personal version) and there it threw no error there. I changed it to 2.13 on colab and now the test code snippet `python3 -c "import keras;print(keras.saving.saving_lib.saving_v3_enabled())"` threw an error. What are your python/TensorFlow/Keras versions?

Comment: This code is using a **Kaggle** dataset, that was used for a competition:
Example using **Colab** notebook:
1. Upload your *kaggle.json* API key file (from your Kaggle account's)
>> `from google.colab import files`
>> `files.upload()  -- browse to file`

2. Copy file:
>> `!cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/`
>> `!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json`

3. Download (needs to accept disclaimer: https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/rules):
>> `!kaggle competitions download -c dogs-vs-cats`

>> `!unzip -qq dogs-vs-cats.zip`
>> `!unzip -qq train.zip`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, there seems to be a weird behaviour related to keras saving and also versioning of TF/Keras. I could replicate your error when running TF/Keras with version 2.13 (newest right now) on colab. Standard install on colab is 2.12, where the error doesn't come up.
So one solution would be to downgrade TF/Keras to 2.12.x, or change

```
keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath="convnet_from_scratch.keras",
        ..)
```

to

```
keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath="convnet_from_scratch.x",
        ..)
```

where x stands for whatever you fancy (NOT "keras") to not save in the `.keras` format.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the format from .keras to .tf works for me (note the save format line):

```
callbacks = [
keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath="convnet_from_scratch.tf",
    save_best_only=True,
    monitor="val_loss",
    save_format="tf")
]
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=30,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    callbacks=callbacks)
```

and later you'd want:

```
test_model = keras.models.load_model("convnet_from_scratch.tf")
test_loss, test_acc = test_model.evaluate(test_dataset)
print(f"Test accuracy: {test_acc:.3f}")
```

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow team did not modify the ModelCheckpoint. The error occurs because there should not be an argument called "options" when saving the model, but ModelCheckpoint includes it.

The solution is to remove that part manually. Go to the location where ModelCheckpoint is defined (if you are using VSCode, it can be easily done).

Find the following line using Ctrl+F:
"options=self._options,"

Replace all occurrences with empty spaces and save. This will resolve the issue.

Comment: While you are right on the error, I would not recommend changing code inside a installed package. Instead, write an issue to them and let the package manger fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with TensorFlow 2.14.0. Updating to TensorFlow 2.15.0 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is best if you create your own `ModelCheckPoint` function:

```
def save_model_checkpoint(epoch, logs):
    if logs['val_loss'] < save_model_checkpoint.best_val_loss:
        save_model_checkpoint.best_val_loss = logs['val_loss']
        model.save_weights(new_base_dir / 'model_checkpoint')
        print('Model checkpoint saved.')

save_model_checkpoint.best_val_loss = float('inf')

# Initialize your model here

model.fit(
    # Other model.fit arguments...
    callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=save_model_checkpoint)]
 )
```

The `save_model_checkpoint` function is defined to monitor the validation loss and save the weights of the best model. It is called at the end of each epoch.
The `best_val_loss` attribute of the `save_model_checkpoint` function is initialized to `float('inf')` to track the best validation loss seen so far.
Inside the function, if the current validation loss (`logs['val_loss']`) is lower than the `best_val_loss`, the `best_val_loss` is updated, and the model weights are saved using `model.save_weights()`. You can customize the saving path and filename as needed.
During the `model.fit()` call, you can pass the `save_model_checkpoint` function as a callback using `tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=save_model_checkpoint)`. This ensures that the `save_model_checkpoint` function is called at the end of each epoch.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the square brackets when passing the argument (eg. callbacks=checkpoint instead of callbacks=[checkpoint]).

Answer (score 0):

Using the argument *None* for the parameter **options** solved the error for me:

```
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath="tmp_file.keras",
    options=None
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
filepath="convnet_from_scratch.ckpt",
..)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).